# Showing that a recurrence relation is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Suppose $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ satisfies $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_n+1}-1$ and that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_n\in(-1,0).$

How would I show that the sequence described by this recurrence relation is increasing?

Comment: You have that $(x_{n+1}+1)^2=x_n+1$, but $0< x_{n+1}+1 <1$, so $$x_{n+1}+1>(x_{n+1}+1)^2=x_n+1,$$ then $x_{n+1}>x_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting
$y_n = -x_n$,
then
$x_{n+1}
=\sqrt{x_n+1}-1
$
becomes
$-y_{n+1}
=\sqrt{-y_n+1}-1
$
or
$y_{n+1}
=1-\sqrt{1-y_n}
$.

Therefore
$1-y_{n+1}
=\sqrt{1-y_n}
$.

Letting
$z_n = 1-y_n$,
this is
$z_{n+1}
=\sqrt{z_n}
$.

If
$0 < z_n < 1$,
then
$0 < z_{n+1} < 1$
and
$z_{n+1}
\gt z_n$
so
$1-y_{n+1}
\gt 1-y_n
$
so
$y_{n+1}
\lt y_n$
so
$x_{n+1}
\gt x_n
$.